# Python Script Using Amazon Product API Not Functioning

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

```
import re
```

import time
import urllib
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
import codecs
import xml.etree.cElementTree as EF
from datetime import date

## import bitly_api

def aws_signed_request(region, params, public_key, private_key, associate_tag=None, version='2011-08-01'):

```
# some paramters
method = 'GET'
host = 'webservices.amazon.' + region
uri = '/onca/xml'

# additional parameters
params['Service'] = 'AWSECommerceService'
params['AWSAccessKeyId'] = public_key
params['Timestamp'] = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', time.gmtime())
params['Version'] = version
if associate_tag:
    params['AssociateTag'] = associate_tag

# create the canonicalized query
canonicalized_query = [urllib.quote(param).replace('%7E', '~') + '=' + urllib.quote(params[param]).replace('%7E', '~')
                        for param in sorted(params.keys())]
canonicalized_query = '&'.join(canonicalized_query)

# create the string to sign
string_to_sign = method + '\n' + host + '\n' + uri + '\n' + canonicalized_query
#print string_to_sign

# calculate HMAC with SHA256 and base64-encoding
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key=private_key, msg=string_to_sign, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())

# encode the signature for the request
signature = urllib.quote(signature).replace('%7E', '~')

print 'http://' + host + uri + '?' + canonicalized_query + '&Signature=' + signature
return 'http://' + host + uri + '?' + canonicalized_query + '&Signature=' + signature
```

This is part of my code that used to be functional. It would get the best selling Amazon items in several categories. However, this script is not longer functioning. Does anyone notice anything wrong?

Comment: I had some trouble formatting the code in my post. You can view the code here: http://www.ulrichmierendorff.com/files/aws_hmac_signer/aws_signed_request_python-1.0.zip

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, my public and private key was expired